# Kendo MVC Chart - Render event issues

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

So I'm using Telerik's Kendo MVC wrapper to render a bar chart.

When the Render event is triggered, I enter a JavaScript function; however, I'm getting myself into an infinite loop when I try to resize the chart using the `setOptions()` method.

For example:

```js
onRender: function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("Render");
        var compareChart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");        

        var wt = compareChart.element.parent().width();
        var ht = compareChart.element.parent().parent().height()
     
        // **** THIS CAUSES TO TRIGGER onRender INFINITELY ****
        compareChart.setOptions({ chartArea: { height: ht, width: wt } });

        return;
    }
```

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
   .Name("chart")
   .ChartArea()
   .series.Bar()
   .Events(events => events
   .Render("onRender")      // *** ON RENDER EVENT ***
 )
```

I suspect that I must use something like `e.preventDefault();` but not sure how to set that in the Kendo wrapper definition:

```
  .Events(events => events
       .Render("Whatif.onRender")     
  )
```

How can I cancel my custom `onRender` js function once I call the `compareChart.setOptions` Kendo method.

your advice is appreciated...

thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind and bind kendo events in javascript. For example try something like:

```
compareChart.unbind('render');
compareChart.setOptions({ chartArea: { height: ht, width: wt } });
compareChart.bind('render', onRender);  //Probably need to prefix onRender with the parent object
```

Hopefully that will mean your function will not trigger again whilst setOptions runs. Of course there is no need to bind the event again if you only need it to run once.

As an aside, preventDefault() only stops any associated DOM events from firing and not those triggered by kendo code.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow. I added a global js Boolean var as a hack, and it worked; however not ideal.